# (C#) Errors when Tetris blocks are moving

Tags: c#, arrays, tetris

Just a note to everyone beforehands. This is my first ever programming class so do bear with me when I don't understand everything.

Basically, for my class final project I decided to recreate Tetris in c# (visual studio). Sounds easy right? Well....

Right now the issue lies with moving the block over. It moves, however, there are issues when it is being moved. The block disappears when you move it over to the right.

here is the method at hand:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
{
    //run move shape right loop
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < width; n++)
        {
            // check to see if movable first and occupied
            if (tetris_grid[n, i, 1] == 0 && tetris_grid[n, i, 0] > 0) //if movable
            {
                if (n == width - 1)  //if at the edge
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else if (tetris_grid[n + 1, i, 1] > 0)
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    tetris_grid[n + 1, i, 0] = tetris_grid[n, i, 0]; //move the contents over
                    tetris_grid[n, i, 0] = 0;  //set the previous location to empty
                    tetris_grid[n + 1, i, 1] = tetris_grid[n, i, 1];
                    tetris_grid[n, i, 1] = 0;  //set the previous location to empty

                    n = n + 1;  //increment so we don't automatically move to edge
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //redraw
    draw_board();
}
```

A disclaimer: Ive been asking my professor for help so the move code is all written by him. I initially had it where the initial array was moving its contents into another array, however he rewrote my code so that it was just a 3d array with a dimension to measure whether or not the block was planted or not.

I've looked through stack overflow but a lot of it uses code that I've never really learned before, also my professor told me not to use stack overflow but I can't help it cause I'm so stuck.

Thanks for all the possible help!

Comment: First, you have to post your code here. External linking is discouraged because there is no guarantee the external link will be up for future visitors to see the code. Second, you can't just dump your code and say "find the problem for me." You have to show some effort you've tried something, then post the *relevant* code sections, what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. Finally, you need to ask a specific question; there is no question her. Please read this *carefully*: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please independently test your methods to see which one is malfunctioning, and narrow down the snippet in your question to focus only on that portion of code.

Comment: ...I have been putting effort into trying to fix the issue. The reason why I'm so confused is because the code should work, and I've already debugged it but the block keeps disappearing when I shift it over. I'm just trying to fix piece of the code...

Comment: Set a break point after you make the move, when the block is disappearing. Are all of the values what they should be? If so, is it a display issue? Are you redrawing the board after the move?

Comment: the board is being redrawn everytime. I'm not one hundred percent sure but the values seems to be correct, considering some of the blocks are moving properly. I don't believe it to be a display issue. I wanted to post the whole code because it would make more sense to see the whole thing but as the first comment states you're not allowed to.

Comment: Please tell us a little just how the 'drawing' happens! Is this Winforms or WPF or what? Are you drawing by painting pixels or are you moving controls?

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic to move your box in a method(MyLogic(KeyCode kcode)), then on the keydown event that you use, call the method passing the parameters MyLogic(Keys.D). After you make your logic of how to move your box inside the matrix. Call Invalidate() method to refresh the board that you pain. OnPaint() event should have just the logic of painting the board.

```
OnKeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e){
   MyLogic(e.KeyCode); //I can remember but this is the idea
   myControlBoard.Invalidate();
}

OnPaint(object sender, EventArgs e){
 for(int i = 0; i < mybox.GetLenght(0); i ++)
  for(int j = 0; j < mybox.GetLenght(1); j++)
  { 
     DrawBox(i, j)
  }
}
```